# Using package "amsmath" is causing overfull errors throughout my document

Tags: equations, errors

Basically I am writing summary notes in the Overleaf LaTeX editor, using packages `ragged2e`, `amssymb` and `amsfonts`. I have the entire document formatted `flushleft` as I prefer this layout.

However when I `\usepackage{amsmath}` in the preamble it causes multiple overfull errors, where text that was previously broken into multiple lines becomes one long line that extends beyond the right margin.

Is there any way to stop this from happening, because I need to use the `amsmath` package for matrices.

Thank you!

*EDIT* 
All parts of the preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{Semester 1, 2020}
%Document begins here
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\maketitle
\pagebreak
```

Code with these symptoms:

```
\text{A local minimum$x*$ of $f$ on $[a,b]$ is a point satisfying $\exists\epsilon>0\; \forall x\in[a,b] \;s.t\; |\,x-x*|\,<\epsilon\Longrightarrow f(x*)\leq f(x)$.}\break
\break
```

Comment: Welcome! In its current form your question cannot be answered. Please post some minimal compilable code that has these symptoms.

Comment: Try with using `mathtools` package instead of `amsmath`, which includes that package by auto, but without `MWE` not able to find out the exact issue...

Comment: An example is given below, error is "overfull \hbox (122.94641pt too wide) * BEGIN CODE*                                                                                                                                          
\text{A local minimum$x*$ of $f$ on $[a,b]$ is a point satisfying $\exists\epsilon>0\; \forall x\in[a,b] \;s.t\; |\,x-x*|\,<\epsilon\Longrightarrow f(x*)\leq f(x)$.}\break
\break

Comment: `\text` is meant to be used for short text inclusions in math displays.  It is *not* the same sort of command as `\abstract`, which is meant to identify a relatively undelimited text block.  You should also have gotten errors saying that you are not in math mode.

Comment: Ok, I seem to have fixed the issue by starting the text with \mathbb{} instead of \text{}.

Comment: `\mathbb{}` doesn't make sense in the brief example shown in your question.  Please provide a brief compilable file that shows what you are really trying to do.

Comment: When I changed the command from \text{} to \mathbb{} in the example code given it output the correctly formatted text on the PDF- I am unsure why/how this worked but it formatted it back to exactly how it was before including the amsmath package in the premable. Thank you :)